# Can't deploy a basic Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, deployment

First of all I am a newbie with Ruby on Rails so sorry if the question seem stupid.

I am following a tutorial about Heroku for Rails app and when I run `git push heroku master` and go to check on the actual website, I get this message:
We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

When I run heroku logs in my console, I get the following:

```
2018-05-20T03:33:23.748800+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:33:23.554110+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:33:23.748800+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:33:23.554110+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:33:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:34:29.457658+00:00 app[api]: Set LANG, RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:34:29.457658+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:34:30.828730+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:34:30.828730+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-tapered-27211) by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:34:31.131189+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to console@0:Free rake@0:Free web@1:Free worker@0:Free by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:34:31.115804+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:34:31.115804+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0248e11a by user xxx.romain@gmail.com
2018-05-20T03:34:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-05-20T03:34:36.168184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 57618 -e production`
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855283+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855302+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.6 application starting in production
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855303+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855305+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855313+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.11.4 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Love Song
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855315+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855316+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855503+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:57618
2018-05-20T03:34:41.855969+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-05-20T03:34:42.411033+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-05-20T03:34:43.450895+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1] Started GET "/" for 27.32.8.50 at 2018-05-20 03:34:43 +0000
2018-05-20T03:34:43.487004+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]   Rendering keywords/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-05-20T03:34:43.463124+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1] Processing by KeywordsController#index as HTML
2018-05-20T03:34:44.722888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tweetscoperm.herokuapp.com request_id=5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1 fwd="27.32.8.50" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1278ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2018-05-20T03:34:44.715829+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]   Keyword Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords"
2018-05-20T03:34:44.717471+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]   Rendered keywords/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1230.3ms)
2018-05-20T03:34:44.717773+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1254ms (ActiveRecord: 33.5ms)
2018-05-20T03:34:44.719239+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720128+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1] ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "keywords" does not exist
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720132+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720130+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords"
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720134+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords"):
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720461+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]     11:   </thead>
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720464+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]     12:
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720466+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]     13:   <tbody>
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720468+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]     14:     <% @keywords.each do |keyword| %>
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720469+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]     15:       <tr>
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720471+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]     16:         <td><%= keyword.word %></td>
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720473+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]     17:         <td><%= link_to 'Show', keyword %></td>
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720531+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1]
2018-05-20T03:34:44.720593+00:00 app[web.1]: [5a2cc1ab-9701-42e6-accc-2f372ff837f1] app/views/keywords/index.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_keywords_index_html_erb___2939922413078681924_23601960'
2018-05-20T03:34:45.523130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tweetscoperm.herokuapp.com request_id=ec46bf49-b91c-4bf2-b017-a15b4cef63a8 fwd="27.32.8.50" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
```

Looking at that, I couldn't find any reason that would cause a problem.

So far, here is how my database.yml file looks like:

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 database: tscope_dev
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

test:
 adapter: postgresql
 database: tscope_test
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

production:
 adapter: postgresql
 database: tscope_production
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
```

And my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'

# Using PostgreSQL as DB
gem 'pg'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

ruby '2.3.4'
```

I created the databse and did the migrations and also ran `bundle install` as well. It is the most basic application with just one controller generated with a scaffold.

Does anybody has any idea of what could be the problem? Even the smallest tip would help me since I really don't know what to look at right now.

If you need any futher information about my code, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**
Solved this issue by running `heroku run rake db:migrate`in the console.
Turned out I haven't ran the migration on Heroku.

Comment: Did you run the migrations on Heroku? Or just on local? To run on Heroku, do `heroku run rake db:migrate` from your console.

Comment: I just tried that and that's the output I get:
    `heroku run db:migrate`
    `Running db:create on ⬢ tweetscoperm... up, run.7410 (Free)`
    `bash: db:create: command not found`

Still got the same error message...

Comment: That actually fixed the problem. For some reason I actually had to pass the command `heroku run RAKE db:migrate`but that eventually solved it. Thanks a looooot for your help :)

Comment: Yep. I figured. My original comment had exactly `heroku run rake db:migrate`, so glad you got it. Added as an answer so you can upvote/accept for future SO seekers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "keywords" does not exist
```

suggests you haven't run your migrations on heroku.

To do that, in your console do:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```